Editing a table using JavaScript using contentEditable attribute
After editing the data and clicking on the save changes button, the data is altered in the screen but it is not updated in the database
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myDB");

if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $vegName = htmlspecialchars($row['vegName']);
        $price = htmlspecialchars($row['price']);
        $isnew = $row['isnew'];
        $id = intval($row['id']); 

        if ($isnew === 'true') {
            $query = "INSERT INTO priceList (vegetable, price) VALUES (?, ?)";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
            if (!$stmt) {
                echo "Prepare failed: (" . mysqli_error($con) . ")"; 
                continue; 
            }
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $vegName, $price);
        } else {
            $query = "UPDATE priceList SET vegetable = ?, price = ? WHERE id = ?";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
            if (!$stmt) {
                echo "Prepare failed: (" . mysqli_error($con) . ")"; 
                continue; 
            }
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $vegName, $price, $id);
        }

        if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) . ")"; 
        } else {
            echo "Changes saved for $vegName!";
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
    }
    
    exit; 
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vegetable Price List</title>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FAEBD7">
    <div>
    <h1>Vegetable Price List</h1>
    <table id="vegTable">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Vegetable</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        
        $sql = "SELECT vegetable, price, id FROM priceList"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "<tr data-isnew='false'>
                        <td contenteditable='true'>" . htmlspecialchars($row["id"]) . "</td>
                        <td contenteditable='true' data-vegname='" . htmlspecialchars($row["vegetable"]) . "'>" . htmlspecialchars($row["vegetable"]) . "</td>
                        <td contenteditable='true'>" . htmlspecialchars($row["price"]) . "</td>
                      </tr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>No vegetables found.</td></tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="saveChanges()">Save Changes</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Add Vegetable</button>

    <script>
        function saveChanges() {
            var table = document.getElementById('vegTable');
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var data = [];

            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) { 
                var vegName = rows[i].cells[1].getAttribute('data-vegname') || rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
                var price = rows[i].cells[2].innerText;
                var id = rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
                var isnew = rows[i].getAttribute('data-isnew') === 'true';
                data.push({ vegName: vegName, price: price, isnew: isnew, id: id });
            }

            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onload = function () {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            };
            xhr.send('data=' + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        
        function addRow() {
            var table = document.getElementById('vegTable');
            var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
            newRow.setAttribute('data-isnew', 'true');

            var idCell = document.createElement('td');
            idCell.textContent = ""; 
            newRow.appendChild(idCell);

            var vegCell = document.createElement('td');
            vegCell.contentEditable = "true";
            vegCell.textContent = "";
            newRow.appendChild(vegCell);

            var priceCell = document.createElement("td");
            priceCell.contentEditable = "true";
            priceCell.textContent = "";
            newRow.appendChild(priceCell);

            table.appendChild(newRow);
        }
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

mysqli_close($con);
?>


I was trying to create a user friendly editable vegetable management system and failed. The issue is with the db since it not getting update once the table is edited and the save changes button is pressed.

With a prepared statement in general you prepare the statement once outside any loops and execute multiple times within the loop

Hello I found most of your code works, you are able to update prices of existing vegetables if there are some already in the table but your code has a bug in it which prevents new vegetables from being added and I think this might be what your asking about?
The reason it doesn't save to the database when you add a new vegetable is because of this line in your PHP
if ($isnew === 'true') {

This is because you are using === and it is doing a literal comparison, meaning its checking to see if $isnew is a string with text 'true'. $isnew is a Boolean value so this is returning false.
If you change your code so that it is doing a literal comparison to a Boolean like this:
if ($isnew === true) { // notice the ' have been removed

It works and you are able to save new vegetables to the database.
Whilst this solution allows you to save new vegetables to the database, you still a little way to go before you can update the newly added vegetables without refreshing the page. This is because there is no ID being populated on the table form when the new vegetables are created in the DB. Also, vegetables will get added multiple times if they are new and you click the 'Save changes' button more than once.
NB: In PHP, the triple equals (===) is a    that checks both value and data type for equality
